# select2 not behaving properly with Datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables, jquery-select2

I am trying to use `select2` with Datatables to render a dropdown multi-select option on a table. However it does not seem to behave well even after following the basic example as described [here](https://select2.org/getting-started/basic-usage).

```
    import $ from 'jquery';
    import 'datatables.net';
    import 'datatables.net-dt/css/jquery.dataTables.css';
    import 'select2';

    var table = $('#failTable').DataTable({
          destroy: true,
          paginate: false,
          scrollY: 300,
          data: fail,
          columns: [{
            title: "Example",
            render: function(data, type, row) {
              var depts = getCurrentMapping('departments');
              let content = "<select class='form-control' name='' id='' placeholder='Select a dept...' multiple='multiple'>";
              for (var dept in depts) {
                content += "<option value='" + depts[dept] + "'>" + dept + "</option>";
              }
              content += "</select>";
              return content
            }
          }],
          initComplete: function(settings, json) {
            $('.form-control').select2();
          }
        });
```

The result is displaying as below

[image: screenshot 1]

And this is what happens when values are selected

[image: screenshot2]

As you can see, the values are still **all** shown, and the `x` button to cancel a selection does not work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working example.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Select2 + DataTables</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.7/css/select2.min.css">
  <script
    src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script
    src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <script
    src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.7/js/select2.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $('#TestTable').dataTable({
        pageLength: 5, 
        ordering: false, 
        drawCallback: function(dt) {
          console.log("draw() callback; initializing Select2's.");
          $('.experience-jquerySelect2-tag').select2({tags: true, width: "6em"});
        }
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <table class="table-sm table-striped table-condensed" id="TestTable">
    <thead>
      <tr class="small">
        <th scope="col">Drop Down</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td valign="middle" align="left" class="small text-nowrap">
          <span class="form-group">
            <select class="form-control experience-jquerySelect2-tag"
              id="IDexperience1" name="experience" required>
              <option value="Test1">Test 1</option>
              <option value="Test2">Test 2</option>
              <option value="Test3">Test 3</option>
            </select>
          </span>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td valign="middle" align="left" class="small text-nowrap">
          <span class="form-group">
            <select class="form-control experience-jquerySelect2-tag"
              id="IDexperience2" name="experience" required>
              <option value="Test1">Test 2</option>
              <option value="Test2">Test 3</option>
              <option value="Test3">Test 4</option>
            </select>
          </span>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td valign="middle" align="left" class="small text-nowrap">
          <span class="form-group">
            <select class="form-control experience-jquerySelect2-tag"
              id="IDexperience3" name="experience" required>
              <option value="Test1">Test 3</option>
              <option value="Test2">Test 4</option>
              <option value="Test3">Test 5</option>
            </select>
          </span>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td valign="middle" align="left" class="small text-nowrap">
          <span class="form-group">
            <select class="form-control experience-jquerySelect2-tag"
              id="IDexperience4" name="experience" required>
              <option value="Test1">Test 4</option>
              <option value="Test2">Test 5</option>
              <option value="Test3">Test 6</option>
            </select>
          </span>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td valign="middle" align="left" class="small text-nowrap">
          <span class="form-group">
            <select class="form-control experience-jquerySelect2-tag"
              id="IDexperience5" name="experience" required>
              <option value="Test1">Test 5</option>
              <option value="Test2">Test 6</option>
              <option value="Test3">Test 7</option>
            </select>
          </span>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td valign="middle" align="left" class="small text-nowrap">
          <span class="form-group">
            <select class="form-control experience-jquerySelect2-tag"
              id="IDexperience6" name="experience" required>
              <option value="Test1">Test 6</option>
              <option value="Test2">Test 7</option>
              <option value="Test3">Test 8</option>
            </select>
          </span>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td valign="middle" align="left" class="small text-nowrap">
          <span class="form-group">
            <select class="form-control experience-jquerySelect2-tag"
              id="IDexperience7" name="experience" required>
              <option value="Test1">Test 7</option>
              <option value="Test2">Test 8</option>
              <option value="Test3">Test 9</option>
            </select>
          </span>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td valign="middle" align="left" class="small text-nowrap">
          <span class="form-group">
            <select class="form-control experience-jquerySelect2-tag"
              id="IDexperience8" name="experience" required>
              <option value="Test1">Test 8</option>
              <option value="Test2">Test 9</option>
              <option value="Test3">Test 10</option>
            </select>
          </span>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td valign="middle" align="left" class="small text-nowrap">
          <span class="form-group">
            <select class="form-control experience-jquerySelect2-tag"
              id="IDexperience9" name="experience" required>
              <option value="Test1">Test 9</option>
              <option value="Test2">Test 10</option>
              <option value="Test3">Test 11</option>
            </select>
          </span>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td valign="middle" align="left" class="small text-nowrap">
          <span class="form-group">
            <select class="form-control experience-jquerySelect2-tag"
              id="IDexperience10" name="experience" required>
              <option value="Test1">Test 10</option>
              <option value="Test2">Test 11</option>
              <option value="Test3">Test 12</option>
            </select>
          </span>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td valign="middle" align="left" class="small text-nowrap">
          <span class="form-group">
            <select class="form-control experience-jquerySelect2-tag"
              id="IDexperience11" name="experience" required>
              <option value="Test1">Test 11</option>
              <option value="Test2">Test 12</option>
              <option value="Test3">Test 13</option>
            </select>
          </span>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td valign="middle" align="left" class="small text-nowrap">
          <span class="form-group">
            <select class="form-control experience-jquerySelect2-tag"
              id="IDexperience12" name="experience" required>
              <option value="Test1">Test 12</option>
              <option value="Test2">Test 13</option>
              <option value="Test3">Test 14</option>
            </select>
          </span>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use class name other than `form-control` for Select2 control. This generic class is used for all Bootstrap controls and its usage may lead to undesirable behavior.

With DataTables pages other than first do not exist in DOM, so your code only initializes controls on first page.

For example, use `select2-control` class to identify Select2 controls and try using the code below:

```
initComplete: function(settings){
    var api = new $.fn.dataTable.Api( settings );

    // Initialize Select2 control
    $('.select2-control', api.rows().nodes()).select2();
}
```

Please see [Custom control does not work on second page and after](https://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-custom-control-does-not-work-on-second-page/]) for more details.